# Node.js dependson access relationship attribute?

Tags: node.js, relationship, keystonejs, keystone

I have two simple modes:

PresentationType:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');

var PresentationType = new keystone.List('PresentationType', {
    autokey: { from: 'name', path: 'key', unique: true },
});

PresentationType.add({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    t1: { type: Boolean },
    t2: { type: Boolean },
});

PresentationType.relationship({ ref: 'StaticPage', path: 'pages', refPath: 'presentationType' });

PresentationType.register();
```

Static Page:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var StaticPage = new keystone.List('StaticPage', {
    map: { name: 'title' },
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true },
    drilldown: 'presentationType',
});

StaticPage.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    presentationType: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'PresentationType', many: false },
    text1: { type: String, dependsOn: { presentationType.t1: true } },
    text2: { type: String, dependsOn: { presentationType.t2: true } },
});

StaticPage.defaultColumns = 'title';
StaticPage.register();
```

First i create a presentation type that has boolean attributes, text1 and text2

Secondly when i create a page and specify it's presentation type, i want to be able to display certain fields based on the presentation type boolean.

So far i cant seem to find an answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `dependsOn` attribute cannot be used across a relationship field; that field would constantly need to be populated with that relationship. `dependsOn` within a model can only be used within other static fields of the same model (and not across different models.)

http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fields-conditional

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So how can i access model B data within model A?

Comment: You could write a method on the model that populates that field, and accesses the data. From there, you could perform whatever operations you need to on that document. `keystone.list("StaticPage").model.findOne({_id: this._id.toString()}).populate("presentationType")`